# MobRemovalEvent may only be triggered asynchronously (Bukkit, TownyAPI)

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm making a small Bukkit plugin that will allow certain hostile mobs to be on the territory of cities from the Towny plugin. In it I use MobRemovalEvent and MobSpawnRemovalEvent. But an error is being spammed in the console and the plugin does not work.

```
package ru.earthmine.onkrintowns;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class ONKRInTowns extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        registerListeners();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
    }

    private void registerListeners() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new DespawnListener(), this);
    }
}
```

```
package ru.earthmine.onkrintowns;

import com.palmergames.bukkit.towny.event.MobRemovalEvent;
import com.palmergames.bukkit.towny.event.mobs.MobSpawnRemovalEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

public class DespawnListener implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onMobRemovalEvent(MobRemovalEvent event) {
        if(event.getEntity().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("&cКонтролирующий")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onMobSpawnRemovalEvent(MobSpawnRemovalEvent event) {
        if(event.getEntity().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("&cКонтролирующий")) {
            event.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

```
[14:54:25 WARN]: [Towny] Task #44 for Towny v0.99.2.0 generated an exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MobRemovalEvent may only be triggered asynchronously.
at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperEventManager.callEvent(PaperEventManager.java:40) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1985]
at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.callEvent(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:126) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1985]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:617) ~[purpur-api-1.19.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at com.palmergames.bukkit.util.BukkitTools.fireEvent(BukkitTools.java:342) ~[Towny-0.99.2.0.jar:?]
at com.palmergames.bukkit.util.BukkitTools.isEventCancelled(BukkitTools.java:323) ~[Towny-0.99.2.0.jar:?]
at com.palmergames.bukkit.towny.tasks.MobRemovalTimerTask.run(MobRemovalTimerTask.java:115) ~[Towny-0.99.2.0.jar:?]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R3.scheduler.CraftTask.run(CraftTask.java:101) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1985]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_19_R3.scheduler.CraftScheduler.mainThreadHeartbeat(CraftScheduler.java:483) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1985]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.tickChildren(MinecraftServer.java:1510) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1985]
at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.tickChildren(DedicatedServer.java:488) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1985]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.tickServer(MinecraftServer.java:1424) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1985]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1195) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1985]
at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:325) ~[purpur-1.19.4.jar:git-Purpur-1985]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

I have little experience in development, so I don't really understand what needs to be done.

Comment: Please include the sources for `com.palmergames.bukkit.util.BukkitTools`. Your `isEventCancelled` method appears to have a side effect that triggers events. Your stacktrace indicates this method is called from `MobRemovalTimerTask.run()`

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke Sorry, I don't quite understand what needs to be done

Comment: Turns out it isn't your code. This is an error in Towny: https://github.com/TownyAdvanced/Towny/issues/6766. You need to use a newer version of Towny